# Help Using Word 2002 MailMerge to not display if value is blank

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, ms-word, mailmerge

I am using VB.net 2010 to generate a letter from a Word 2002 template. The template has MailMerge bookmarks where the database values will be displayed (for example the letter receiving company's address). Currently I have:

```
«Company Contact»
«Company Name»
«Address1»
«Address2»
«City», «State», «ZipCode»
```

If "Address2" value is blank, then don't display the bookmark in the letter output (hence avoid displaying a blank line)

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: As far as I recall, blank lines used to be suppressed. I wonder if this is relevant http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820734/en-us ?

Comment: "Word 2002 should be suppressing these by default. But it 
won't if there's ANYTHING besides the mail merge field in 
the paragraph; this includes IF fields. (I know, this 
worked in earlier versions!)" -- http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word-mailmerge/3124/Suppressing-Blank-Lines-in-Merge

Comment: does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `<<AddressBlock>>` instead of using the individual merge fields. Empty values will be suppressed. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-addressblock-field-HP003069839.aspx